# Go: How to handle library API changes?

Tags: go

I originally wrote my project with Go v1.9, which includes the `os.LookupEnv` function.

Now I need to build with Go v1.4, but that function is missing -- it only has `os.Getenv` which has slightly different behavior.

In Python, I could provide a compatibility function, something like this:

```
if 'LookupEnv' not in os:
    def myLookupEnv(k):
        v = os.Getenv(k)
        return v, v!=''
    os.LookupEnv = myLookupEnv
```

How can I handle these kinds of API changes in Go?

Comment: you just need to implement interface, so good idea would be to embedded the old lib add missing stuff and pass ur embedded object

Comment: here is a [doc](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) about it

Comment: @Vardius, I am asking about a package-level function, not an object method.  Therefore, it is impossible to use an `interface` for this.

Comment: Then no, you can't override the function, unless it is exported as object func there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use build constraints. A build constraint is a line comment that begins

```
// +build
```

that lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the package. See Build Constraints in [Package build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) for details.

For example, for Go 1.5 and later (`// +build go1.5`), forward `LookupEnv` to `os.LookupEnv`. For Go 1.4 and earlier (`// +build !go1.5`), implement `LookupEnv`.

`src/lookup/lookup.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("version:", runtime.Version())
    key := "HOME"
    value, found := LookupEnv(key)
    fmt.Printf("key: %q value %q found: %t\n", key, value, found)
}
```

`src/lookup/env.go`:

```
// +build go1.5

// Forward LookupEnv to os.LookupEnv

package main

import "os"

// LookupEnv retrieves the value of the environment variable named
// by the key. If the variable is present in the environment the
// value (which may be empty) is returned and the boolean is true.
// Otherwise the returned value will be empty and the boolean will
// be false.
func LookupEnv(key string) (string, bool) {
    return os.LookupEnv(key)
}
```

`src/lookup/env_1.4.go`:

```
// +build !go1.5

// Implement LookupEnv

package main

import "syscall"

// LookupEnv retrieves the value of the environment variable named
// by the key. If the variable is present in the environment the
// value (which may be empty) is returned and the boolean is true.
// Otherwise the returned value will be empty and the boolean will
// be false.
func LookupEnv(key string) (string, bool) {
    return syscall.Getenv(key)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build && ./lookup
version: devel +fd7331a821 Tue Feb 6 05:00:01 2018 +0000
key: "HOME" value "/home/peter" found: true
$

$ go1.4 build && ./lookup
version: go1.4-bootstrap-20170531
key: "HOME" value "/home/peter" found: true
$
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!  Thank you.